# Open "new mail" dialog in mutt with attachment

Tags: mutt, neomutt

Is it possible to open mutt via a commandline flag directly in the "new mail" dialog with a file already attached? I want to make myself a ranger-shortcut to open mutt and attach a file to a mail. Is that possible? Do you have any ideas how I could make that?

Comment: What have you tried already? Is `mutt toto@example.com -a /tmp/file.txt` enough for your use case?

Comment: Actually yes, thanks a lot! I can't believe it was so easy. I was using `echo "some-message" | mutt someone@example.org` already, but I totally forgot to test it without piping a message to stdin. Sometimes you are simply to blind to see the solution, thanks a lot (you should probably change your comment to an answer, so that I can accept it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add one or more attachment files directly when calling mutt. For example:

```
mutt toto@example.com -a /tmp/file1.txt -a /tmp/file2.png -s "subject line"
```

Unless a message body is fed into stdin (like `cat message | mutt ...`), the editor will open for typing in the message body.